# Dynamodb Autoscaling terraform import

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created dynamodb autoscaling out of terraform and I want to import this to terraform. But it says the object does not exists. I used the similar command for other terraform and it worked. But for this , it says autoscaling doesnt exists. No issues with the read and write target. Able to import.

**Command:**

```
terraform import aws_appautoscaling_policy.dynamodb_table_read_policy dynamodb/table/Table_v3/dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits/DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:table/Table_v3
```

**Terraform Code:**

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "dynamodb_table_read_target" {
  max_capacity       = var.read_max_capacity
  min_capacity       = var.read_min_capacity
  resource_id        = "table/${var.table_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
  service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "dynamodb_table_read_policy" {
  name               = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:${aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id}"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization"
    }

    target_value = var.read_target_util
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> aws_appautoscaling_policy.dynamodb_table_read_policy: Importing from
> ID
> "dynamodb/table/Table_v3/dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits/DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:table/Table_v3"...
> aws_appautoscaling_policy.dynamodb_table_read_policy: Import prepared!
> Prepared aws_appautoscaling_policy for import
> aws_appautoscaling_policy.dynamodb_table_read_policy: Refreshing
> state... [id=DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:table/Table_v3] ╷ │
> Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object │  │ While attempting
> to import an existing object to
> "aws_appautoscaling_policy.dynamodb_table_read_policy", the provider
> detected that no object exists with the │ given id. Only pre-existing
> objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is
> associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use
> "terraform apply" to │ create a new remote object for this resource.

Comment: What is your corresponding TF code?

Comment: Updated with tf code @Marcin

Comment: Also what is the full, exact error message?

Comment: Sorry. updated here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PolicyName` (i.e. `DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:table/Table_v3`) looks strange. Sadly, since you haven't provide any information about how exactly you've created the scaling policy outside of TF, I would suggest running:

```
aws application-autoscaling describe-scaling-policies  --service-namespace dynamodb
```

and verifying the `PolicyName`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, strangely it doesnt have autoscaling but just the target and the index autoscaling policy only. But in the console, it does display autoscaling policy enabled

Comment: Policy name when created from the console is different from what I gave. AWS command is the only way to know the exact name. This command helps me lot. Thanks